# Login em C# com base de dados

Tags: c#, login

Estou tentando fazer um painel de login, mas ele não reconhece os dados gravados na base de dados.

Código:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\TutoDS\Desktop\Trabalho Programação - VideoClub\VideoClub\VideoClub\bdVideoClub.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

if (txtPass.Text == "" & txtUser.Text == "") //Campos vazios
{
    MessageBox.Show("Por favor preencha os dados de login!", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    txtPass.Text = "";
    txtUser.Text = "";
}
else if(txtPass.Text == "") //txtPass vazia
{
    MessageBox.Show("Campo Password vazio!", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    txtPass.Text = "";
    txtUser.Text = "";
}
else if(txtUser.Text == "") //txtuser vazia
{
    MessageBox.Show("Campo Utilziador vazio!", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    txtPass.Text = "";
    txtUser.Text = "";
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Por favor verifique os dados de login!", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    txtPass.Text = "";
    txtUser.Text = "";
}


try
{
    con.Open();
    string user = txtUser.Text;
    string pass = txtPass.Text;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE User='" + txtUser.Text + "' AND Pass ='" + txtPass.Text + "'", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        this.Hide();
        //Abre Form Geral caso os dados do Login estejam certos
        Form1 btHome = new Form1();
        btHome.Show();
    }
}
catch(Exception error)
{
    MessageBox.Show(error.Message, "ERRO!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
finally
{
    if  (con != null)
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tente explicar melhor seu problema, não tem como entender o que você precisa desse jeito. Aliás, não precisa escrever "ajuda" no título.

Comment: Aparentemente é uma aplicação Windows Forms. Está dando algum erro?

Comment: Qual erro que dá ? coloque break points e verifique em tempo de execução o que acontece...

Comment: pode começar tirando esse ultimo else do if, que zera os campos se ambos estiverem preenchidos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido o login

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = null; //Conexão começa em Null

    private string strCmd = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\TutoDS\Desktop\VideoClub\VideoClub\VideoClub\bdVideoClub.mdf';Integrated Security=True"; //Conection String da BD

    private string strSQL = string.Empty;

    public bool logado = false;




    public void Sign_in() //Class com as condições do Login
    {
        sqlCon = new SqlConnection(strCmd);

        //Declaração variavéis ( user = txtUser.txt & pass = txtPass.text)
        string senha, uti; 

        try
        {
            //Variáveis = TextBoxs
            uti = txtUser.Text;
            senha = txtPass.Text;

            strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM [Login] WHERE [User] = @utilizador AND [Pass] = @password";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, sqlCon);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@utilizador", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = uti;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = senha;

            sqlCon.Open(); //Abre a conexão com a BD

            int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 

            if(count > 0) //Login com sucesso
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login realizado com sucesso!", "Parabéns!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                logado = true;
                this.Dispose();

            }
            else if (txtPass.Text =="" & txtUser.Text=="") //txtUser & txtPass vazia
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor preencha os campos Utilizador & Password!", "Campos vazios!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtUser.Focus();
                logado = false;
            }
            else if (txtUser.Text == "") //txtUser &vazia
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor preencha o campo Utilizador!", "Campo Utilizador vazio!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtUser.Focus();
                logado = false;
            }
            else if (txtPass.Text == "") //txtPass vazia
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor preencha o campo Password!", "Campo Password vazio!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtPass.Focus();
                logado = false;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Dados de login errados. Por favor verifique os seus daods!", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                logado = false;

            }

        }
        catch(SqlException erro)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(erro + "");
        }
```

Comment: Qual a lógica de verificar se os campos estão em branco depois de executar o sql e der errado o login ?

Comment: Coloco eles antes do try?

Comment: Outra coisa é possível colocar o nome do utilizador logado noutro form?

Comment: Você diz deixar os ifs dos campos vazios antes do try, e depois a outra parte correto?

Comment: Veja o código do FormLogin que postei na minha resposta, na resposta também mostra como passar o usuário logado

Comment: public FormPrincipal(Usuarios _usuarioLogado)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        labelUsuario.Text = _usuarioLogado.Nome;
    }

Comment: Isto certo?
Mas para ele ir buscar esse nome tenho que fazer mais alguma coisa no form de login?

Comment: No meu exemplo eu retornei um objeto Usuario no método que valida o login

Comment: Como voce faz o insert do usuário ?

Comment: Eu inseri o usuário através do show data table no c#

Comment: E na aplicação, não terá opção de cadastro? Tens conhecimento de classes e objetos?

Comment: Não.Eu estou num curso que me dá o nivel 5, se chama CET aqui em portugal.
Só que a minha turma não entende de programação nem tem muito interesse, então o professor ainda não deu nada de muito complicado, eu é que tenho tentado aprender pedindo ajudas

Comment: Certo, vou olhar um material para te ajudar e ja te passo, estou no horário de almoço, assim que voltar posto novamente

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, tá ajudando de mais.
Quanto ao cadastro para já não será necessário, visto que o programa é para um gerente de video club, mas se conseguisse colocar o nome do usuario logado nos outros forms seria legal.
Uma coisa, eu vou tentar fazer o cadastro de filmes, onde queria adicionar a capa, categoria e assim. para a categoria eu gostaria de usar uma combo box, mas não sei muito bem como elas funcionam.
Se poder ajudar agradeço novamente

Comment: um passo de cada vez, rsrs, veja este vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NY2ENg4ejXk

Comment: Editei a minha resposta alterando seu código de forma simples, se lhe ajudar somente nessa questão do login, marque como resposta, no V verde abaixo da avaliação da resposta

Comment: Obrigado por todo o apoio.Vou tentar testar amanha, vou começar a fazer a parte dos filmes e de como adicionar filmes,o que me vai dar uma dor de cabeça terrível :S

Comment: Caso eu queira fazer isso noutro form sem ser o de login vai mudar muita coisa?

Comment: Então, acho que primeiro deve entender a questão de orientação a objetos, antes de chegar aos Forms. Logo de inicio terá duas classes: Usuarios e Filmes, para então passar a criar a interface com o usuário.

Comment: Ok.é so porque eu queria o nome do user no form Geral.
Obrigado. vou tentar adiantar meu trabalho

Answer (score 3):

*Algumas observações:*

Se o campo senha está vazio, porque obrigar ao usuário a digitar o usuário novamente? basta definir o foco do cursor para o campo senha... `txtPass.Focus();`
Igualmente para a situação oposta.

Para verificar se uma `string` é vazia, eu utilizo `String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPass.Text);`

Logo abaixo de onde você abre a conexão, você declara duas variáveis:

```
string user = txtUser.Text;
string pass = txtPass.Text;
```

mas não as utiliza para nada.

E, na hora de executar o comando SQL, utilize parâmetros, e não concatene a `string` dessa forma. Do jeito que está um SQL injection está muito fácil.

**Fiz um código bem simples de como faria uma tela de login no seu caso:**

O Form principal da aplicação (o que abre no método `Main` com `Application.Run`) deve ser seu form principal, e não o form de login. Por isso, coloco o dialogo de login e se caso o resultado for OK, continuo com a aplicação e abro o `FormPrincipal`, no seu caso o Form1 ou FormGeral.

**Program:**

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        FormLogin formLogin = new FormLogin();
        if (formLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Application.Run(new FormPrincipal(formLogin.UsuarioLogado));
        }
    }
}
```

**FormLogin:**
Esse seria o código do `FormLogin`:

```
public partial class FormLogin : Form
{
    public Usuarios UsuarioLogado { get; set; }

    public FormLogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //O botão cancela, retorna 'Cancel'
        buttonCancela.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
    }

    //Botão Login ou OK
    private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUser.Text))
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPass.Text))
                {

                    //A rotina que valida o login do usuário, está dentro da 
                    //classe Usuarios, e se for válido, retorna um objeto do 
                    //tipo Usuarios, caso contrário, retorna null
                    UsuarioLogado = Usuarios.ValidarLogin(txtUser.Text, txtPass.Text);

                    if (UsuarioLogado != null)
                    {
                        //Se retornou o usuário, ou seja: é válido, retorna OK
                        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        txtUser.Text = txtPass.Text = "";
                        labelStatus.Text = "Usuario / Senha inválido";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    labelStatus.Text = "Informe a senha do usuário";
                    txtPass.Focus();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                labelStatus.Text = "Informe o nome de usuário";
                txtUser.Focus();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            labelStatus.Text = ex.Message;
        }

    }
}
```

**Usuarios:**
Essa seria uma classe de usuários, aqui ficam as propriedades dos usuários, e métodos de Insert / Update / Delete, além do método de validar login que é utilizado no FormLogin

```
public class Usuarios
{
    public string Usuario { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    //Quaisquer outras propriedades

    public static Usuarios ValidarLogin(string _user, string _senha)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\TutoDS\Desktop\Trabalho Programação - VideoClub\VideoClub\VideoClub\bdVideoClub.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE User= @usuario AND Pass = @senha;", con);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@usuario", _user));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@senha", _senha));

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            Usuarios obj = new Usuarios();
            obj.Nome = reader["coluna_nome"].ToString();
            obj.Usuario = reader["User"].ToString();

            return obj;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

}
```

**FormPrincipal:**
No FormPrincipal, no seu construtor, coloquei um parâmetro do tipo Usuarios que será o usuário logado na aplicação, a partir daí você pode ter qual usuário está utilizando o sistema.

```
public partial class FormPrincipal : Form
{
    public FormPrincipal(Usuarios _usuarioLogado)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        labelUsuario.Text = _usuarioLogado.Nome;
    }
}
```

Tentei não estender muito, se algum outro membro tiver sugestões fiquem à vontade. Qualquer dúvida, à disposição.

**Fiz as alterações no seu código, sem levar em conta as observações que lhe passei, e conceitos de orientação a objeto:**

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = null; //Conexão começa em Null

private string strCmd = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\TutoDS\Desktop\VideoClub\VideoClub\VideoClub\bdVideoClub.mdf';Integrated Security=True"; //Conection String da BD

private string strSQL = string.Empty;

public bool logado = false;


public void Sign_in()
{

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUser.Text))
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPass.Text))
        {
            string usuarioLogado =null;


            try
            {
                sqlCon = new SqlConnection(strCmd);
                strSQL = "SELECT Nome FROM [Login] WHERE [User] = @utilizador AND [Pass] = @password";                      
                sqlCon.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@utilizador", txtUser.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", txtPass.Text));

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    //usuário é válido e o nome está na variável usuarioLogado
                    logado = true;
                    usuarioLogado = reader["Nome"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    //usuário não é válido
                    txtUser.Text = txtPass.Text = "";
                    labelStatus.Text = "Usuario / Senha inválido";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            labelStatus.Text = "Informe a senha do usuário";
            txtPass.Focus();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        labelStatus.Text = "Informe o nome de usuário";
        txtUser.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Uma coisa importante: não só é complicado demais verificar o par de autenticação separadamente já que 3 `ifs` são necessários, como é inseguro já que entrega qual deles já está certo e o invasor não precisa mais tentar acertá-lo na força bruta, só o outro. E acho que isto não responde a questão.

Comment: Na verdade ele verifica apenas se os campos estão preenchidos, nesse ponto acredito que não cabe a questão da segurança, apenas usabilidade do usuário. E apenas mostrei o erro na lógica dele que está impedindo o login, uma vez que sempre será executado o comando SQL com login e senha vazios.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis acho que seria interessante outros adendos na resposta sobre as partes do código que não estão boas. Mesmo se tratando apenas de estudo, mas é interessante ele e todos que verem a questão já aprenderem como não fazer.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann sim, o problema é estender demais a questão, mas fique à vontade para editar ou sugerir. Apenas observei as partes mais simples.