# Pegar conteudo de uma textbox de outro frame

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, textbox

Pessoal preciso de uma ajudinha, eu tenho uma aplicativo que prescisa pegar o conteudo de um textBox em outro form para colocar em um mesageBox de boas vindas.

```
        private void PDVForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Operador = "";//qual o codigo que vai aqui?;
        MessageBox.Show("Olá " + Operador,"Bem-Vindo",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

Comment: aqui tem um exemplo de um formulário de login: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205488/69359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu receberia o nome do operador no construtor do PDVForm

No outro formulário ficaria assim

```
private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PDVForm form = new PDVForm(txtOperador.Text);
    form.Show();
}
```

No PDVForm

```
public partial class PDVForm : Form
    {
        private string operador;

        public PDVForm(string Operador)
        {
            operador = Operador;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PDVForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            MessageBox.Show("Olá " + operador, "Bem-Vindo",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Obviamente não estou levando em consideração as regras de validação.