# Parar a aplicação depois de apresentar um erro de login

Tags: c#

No código abaixo, a aplicação desktop tem que fazer um login em um sistema, mas, quando o usuário/senha está errado, ele me dá a mensagem de erro, mas após eu dar o OK ele continua rodando. Tentei o `environment.exit()` e `application.exit()` mas não funcionaram. Não aconteceu nada.
Como faria para parar a aplicação e começar de novo? Ou voltar de onde parou?

```
public void ConsultarSistemaRJ(string codPrograma)
        {

            log.GravarLog("Sistema RJ", "");

            r.Espera("SELECIONE A OP", 17, 16, 29 );

            r.PutString("6", 17, 38);
            r.PutString("29", 17, 41);
            r.EnviaEnter();
            r.PutString(matricula, 8, 58);
            r.PutString(senha, 9, 58);
            r.EnviaEnter();

            **if (r.txTela.Contains("CEFSNP"))
            {
                login = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Login inválido!");
                return;
            }
            if (login == false)
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }**


            r.Espera("PAS SIPAS", 11, 27, 35);

            r.PutString("PAS", 4, 15);
            r.EnviaEnter();
            r.PutString("001", 5, 15);
            r.EnviaEnter();
```

Comment: veja se ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/205483/login-em-c-com-base-de-dados/205488#205488

Comment: a execução do `Application.Exit()` não é imediata, ele apenas sinaliza para o SO que a aplicação vai encerrar e depois encerra (qq coisa executando depois da linha irá executar), se o seu form for o principal da aplicação vc pode chamar `Close()` pra fechar o form e a aplicação irá encerrar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que era só colocar um *return* para parar o método(o que tinha nesse código acima), mas aí próximo método executava, o que ferrava tudo, pois o método anterior havia sido interrompido. Criei uma variável *bool* para que não executasse quando fosse false.